# Is there any way to split the bottom view of intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

If I open one new view like class hierarchy view, it would always override the previous bottom view. Is there any way to keep the original view and split the bottom view for the new view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click a toolwindow button and select the "Split mode" option. This allows you to have two toolwindows visible at the same time on each side of the screen.